# APScheduler2.1.2 installed on python2.7, but still ImportError: No module named 'apscheduler'

Tags: python-2.7, apscheduler

[Command Line activity Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZXoe.png)

1. I have Python2.7 on windows.
2. Installed scheduler as 
   $pip install apscheduler==2.1.2
3. pip Listing shows the scheduler2.1.2

But keep getting:

```
U:\>python
Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 07:43:08) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named apscheduler.schedulers.blocking
>>> quit()
```

It look much cleaner in the image. 
Thanks.

Comment: have you checked to see if its in the python 2.7 site packages directory? I had this issue with a library only to find I'd put it in my Python 3 directory

Comment: It seems I have 2 "site-package" paths. APScheduler2.1.2 is in none of them .  ?!???  1. c:\users\mlashkar\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages
2. C:\Python27\lib\site-packages

Comment: it needs to be in th Python27 one. I would try moving to `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages` then runing `pip install apscheduler==2.1.2`